# Profile curve alignment of the curve to mesh node

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to align the circle of the profile curve so as to avoid the distortion shown in the attached image? I would like a perfect cylindrical sinusoid as much as possible.
[image: sinusoid]
Here are the nodes I used.
[[image: nodes used2]Thanks.

Comment: yeah. just do the deformation before the curve to mesh.
(offset the curve instead of the profile.)

Comment: Very appreciated.